# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is Blank inside [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am redirecting my users to this ActionResult when they click login and are authenticated.  It brings them to this method:

```
[Authorize]
private ActionResult RouteRegistrationStep()
{
    Debug.Print(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString()); // false
    Debug.Print(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name); // blank
    return RedirectToAction("ContactInfo", "Adjuster");
}
```

How is `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString()` false?  And, if it is false, why did the `[Authorize]` attribute let it in the method to begin with?

**Edit:**

This is the login method which redirects them to `RouteRegistrationStep()`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && db.Users.Where(x => x.username == model.username 
        && x.password == EncryptPassword(model.password)).Count() > 0)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.username, model.RememberMe);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}

[Authorize]
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RouteRegistrationStep();
    }
}
```

Comment: `[Authorize]` doesn't apply to methods that you call yourself AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's interesting.  Do you propose I use a class property to store my user name as opposed to using `httpcontext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action filters are only applied to public action methods, not private ones.

Also, the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method writes a cookie to the HTTP response, which isn't available until the next request. You'll need to do a redirect before users are authorized. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx):

> The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication
>   information to the next request made by the browser.

So after setting the auth cookie, redirect the user to another action that has the `Authorize` attribute and it should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you please elaborate?  It seems I already am redirecting them after they have been authorized.

Comment: Does the target of the redirection (`ContactInfo` in `AdjusterController`) have the `Authorize` attribute on it?

Comment: Yes, ContactInfo in AdjusterController has the `[Authorize]` attr.

Comment: Your original questions were "why is `IsAuthenticated` false?" and "why didn't the `Authorize` attribute work?". My answer covers both those issues. Are you saying that once you get to the `ContactInfo` action in `AdjusterController` that the `IsAuthenticated` property is STILL false?

Comment: No, I'm sorry you are correct.  I was just hoping for a solution which would enable me to retrieve httpcontext data in my `RouteRegistrationStep()` method.  But, you seem to be saying that it is impossible.

Comment: You could do 2 redirects, the first that queries the `IsAuthenticated` and `Name` properties - maybe pass the target URL to this - or persist the return URL that was originally passed in. Then do another redirect to the target method (in this case `ContactInfo` in `AdjusterController`). Or, maybe a better solution, as you've already identified that a user is logged in at this point, you could pass the `User` instance that you extracted from the `db.Users` collection and use the `username` property from that.

Comment: Thanks, again.  I basically did that (pass the user instance to a class property) but I didn't pass the whole instance, just the name (as a string).